# Flask - Firebase Storage - Image upload

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-storage, pyrebase

Im trying to allow users to upload images to my firebase storage database this way:

```
import pyrebase
from flask import *
app = Flask(__name__)

config = {
    #Hidden
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()
auth = firebase.auth()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#Login
def basic():
    unsuccessful = 'Please check your credentials'
    successful = 'Login successful'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['name']
        password = request.form['pass']
        try:
            auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            return render_template('index.html', s=successful)
        except:
            return render_template('new.html', us=unsuccessful)
    return render_template('new.html')

#Posting function
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def newProduct():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            path_on_cloud = "images/newproduct.jpg"
            path_local=request.form['file']
            storage.child(path_on_cloud).put(path_local)
            return render_template("index.html")
        except:
            return render_template("index.html")
```

The basic function which allows the users to log in works without any issues.
However i get the following 404 error when trying to upload a picture to the firebase storage database:
"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

i have two html files: new.html which contains the log in, and index.html which is the page that follows where the upload of an image is done.

I hope one of you can see what i've done wrong or what im missing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: both the functions have the same route. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 2):

From the code that you shared, you have the same @app.route for both pages. Each one should have their own @app.route.

Posting function should be:

```
@app.route('/newProduct', methods=['GET','POST'])
```

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/views/

Flask documentation for blueprints and views.